# Can Unicode be used in 'src' attribute of <img> tag instead of a path

Tags: html, image, unicode, src

I was wondering if we could use **Unicode images** in the  `src`  attribute of  `img`  tag instead of a path. Will the browser be able to identify the code?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You have a char, you can just print it, at any size. Check 'initial-letter' (real example) how it is done artisticallly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Images need to be images, not characters from a font.

The value assigned to `src` needs to be the URL to an image. It can't be some text. It can't be the URL to a font.

Answer (score -1):

That's DataURI. [Demo](https://codepen.io/jfw10973/pen/eYdByXp?editors=1100)

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" alt="star">
```

Here is a [document](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

Comment: But the question is "Unicode images" not "character". Attribute "src" could be text just 
 like my demo.."

Comment: I can see two ways of interpreting "Unicode images". 1. "Image like characters such as ". 2. Icon fonts like https://fontawesome.com/ . I can't see it being interpreted as a GIF (which isn't remotely Unicode) or a data: URL (which is made up of ASCII characters)